# Postgresql to BigQuery - Left Join on X and Y

Tags: postgresql, left-join, google-bigquery

I have a table with a column (value) that holds different types of information that I need to parse into separate columns. In postgresql, I can easily do this:

```
SELECT m1.value shipname
     , m2.value agent
FROM maritimeDB m1 
JOIN maritimeDB m2 
  ON m1.rowID = m2.rowID 
  AND m2.itemname = 'Agent'
WHERE m1.rowID 
    IN (SELECT DISTINCT rowID FROM maritimeDB WHERE entity='9999') 
    AND m1.itemname='shipname'
```

I want to do this same sort of query in BigQuery (with JOIN becoming LEFT JOIN), but I get this error:
Error: ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name.

Any suggestions?

Comment: tittle say `LEFT JOIN` but your query say `JOIN`

Comment: Thanks. I've added in a WHERE clause to make it more understandable.

Comment: It has JOIN because the original SQL query is from postgresql. I am trying to rewrite into BigQuery using LEFT JOIN statements, but getting the error message.

Comment: You have to show us the query causing the error. So we can understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is coming from Legacy SQL dialect (which is default). This query should work with [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) dialect which supports arbitrary JOIN predicates.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This was the answer.  I had to reformat the table syntax, but it solved the problem.